# How to retrieve all users in role using GetUsersInRoleAsync Method and display it the view as per below implementation in .net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

This post going to be a bit long so kindly please bear with me. Please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications if required. I will post my current implementation below which works perfectly but I found the built-in function GetUsersInRoleAsync. I would like to know how I can modify my below controller, model, and view to

1. Get User roles using GetUsersInRoleAsync Method
2. Then retrieve those details in my view

### **Current Code Implementation.**

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyApp.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class RoleViewModel
    {
        public RoleViewModel()
        {
            Users = new List<string>();
        }
        public string? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Role Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

        public List<string>? Users { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Read(string? id)
{
    var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (role == null)
    {
        TempData[Helper.ErrorMessage] = "Role not found";
        return View("NotFound");
    }
    var model = new RoleViewModel
    {
        Id = role.Id,
        Name = role.Name
    };
    foreach (var user in userManager.Users)
    {
        if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
        {
            model.Users?.Add(user.UserName);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyApp.Models.RoleViewModel

<form method="get" asp-action="Read">
    <div class="row g-3">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" type="text" disabled readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mt-5">
        <div class="card-header">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="true">Users</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Users</h5>
            <p class="card-text">List of users in this Role</p>
            <div class = "my-3">
            @if (Model?.Users?.Count>0)
            {
                foreach (var user in Model.Users)
                {
                    <li class="card-title">@user</li>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <partial name="_NoData" />
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <partial name="_FooterMenuRead" />
</form>
```

Comment: hi, GetUsersInRoleAsync method returns a list of users from the user store who are members of the specified roleName. Do you want to display all the users in that role?

Comment: Yes precisely. GetUsersInRoleAsync returns data as type of IList<IdentityUser>. I,am unable to return the values to the view without converting IList to List. As my Model is list of users.

Comment: So what is the harm if you convert IList<IdentityUser> to a List. (using a for each loop or directly using linq)

Comment: @AvanthaSiriwardana
Could you please clarify on the solution. I,am not aware on how to convert from IList to List using Linq. Would be better if you could help by modifying my code above.

Comment: Something like this:                                                                                                     
`var usersInRole = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Your Role Name");

foreach (var user in usersInRole)
{      
    // add value to your list    
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to do it without any loops is to modify the controller as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Read(string? id)
{
    var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (role == null)
    {
        TempData[Helper.ErrorMessage] = "Role not found";
        return View("NotFound");
    }
    var userList = await userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role.Name);
    RoleViewModel? model = new()
    {
        Id = role.Id,
        Name = role.Name,
        Users = userList
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Code in View remains same as in question

Answer (score 1):

**you can change your controller like this:**

```
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Read(string? id)
            {
               
                var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
                if (role == null)
                {
                    TempData[Helper.ErrorMessage] = "Role not found";
                    return View("NotFound");
                }
                var model = new RoleViewModel
                {
                    Id = role.Id,
                    Name = role.Name
                };
                
                foreach (var user in await userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role.Name))
                {
                    model.Users?.Add(user.UserName);
                }
                return View(model);
            }
```